# Git ignores core.filemode setting in template

Tags: macos, git, git-config

I've been having a weird problem with git behaviour. It seems that it is ignoring `core.filemode` setting in my template and I want to to be set to `false`.

My system:

- OS X 10.8
- Git 1.7.10.2 (Apple Git-33)

Both, my `~/.gitconfig` and `/usr/share/git-core/templates/config` have this inside:

```
[core]
    filemode = false
```

Yet, every time I do `git init` or `git clone` the setting is changed and set to `true` in `.git/config`. Any ideas why would this be?

Answer (score 1):

As [**documented**](http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html), `git clone` probes the file system to see if it supports permissions and sets the `core.filemode` accordingly *per repository*.

The way I have handled this problem is by adding this to `~/.bash_profile`

```
[ -d .git ] && git config core.filemode false
```

[**source**](http://github.com/svnpenn/dotfiles/blob/master/.extra)